# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

**recyclerView** doesn't show anything

i checked the adapter and its items (notifyDatasetChanged called)
and the calling thread it should be working!

i'm using `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

**ViewClass**:

```
    class HomeView(private val context: Context, swipeRefreshEnabled: Boolean = true) : HomeViewContract {

    private var mRootView: View = context.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home)
    private var mAdapter: HomeAdapter
    private var list: RecyclerView

    init {
        Log.d("HomeView","init called from ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        mAdapter = HomeAdapter()
        this.list = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.home_recycler_view) as RecyclerView
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        linearLayoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
        list.apply{
            adapter = mAdapter
            layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        }
      // ...
    }
}
```

**Fragment**:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var homeView: HomeView

override fun onCreateView(...) = container?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home)
fun make(context: Context){
    this.homeView = HomeView(context)
}
```

**Activity**:

```
val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
            homeFragment.make(this)
            loadFragment(homeFragment)
```

Comment: Please post the code for HomeAdapter. Where is it getting its data from? Have you tried setting breakpoints in any of the adapter methods (onCreateViewHolder(), getItemCount(), for example)?

Answer (score 2):

Your fragment will automatically have its `onCreateView` method called by the framework. The layout created by this call will contain an instance of your `RecyclerView`, and this instance of your layout would be part of the layout process.

What you're doing in `HomeView` is you're inflating another instance of your layout, and adding an adapter to the `RecyclerView` that's in this second instance.

You could, instead, create your `HomeView` in `onViewCreated`, like so:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    this.homeView = HomeView(context, view)
}
```

And then find the `RecyclerView` inside this `View` instance (this is the one that your `onCreateView` method has inflated, the framework is just passing it back to you):

```
class HomeView(private val context: Context, rootView: View, ...) : HomeViewContract {

    private var adapter: HomeAdapter
    private var list: RecyclerView

    init {
        adapter = HomeAdapter()
        list = rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_recycler_view) as RecyclerView
        list.apply {
            adapter = mAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context).apply {
                orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not trying override fun onCreateView(...) = viewHome.getRootView() ? : )